minted with lines, top/bottom margin seems different
I love the minted package! However, when I use it with the 'lines' framing, it appears that the top and bottom margins are just slightly unbalanced, with the bottom margin being just a little bit larger. You can see here that the distance from the top line to the top of the 'f' seems smaller than the distance from the bottom line to the bottom of 'g':

The effect varies depending on the current page and sometimes this effect is more pronounced than in this example. Is there a way to control these margins individually?
Here is some minimal latex which required pygementize and needs to be compiled with pdflatex -shell-escape test:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{minted}{\vspace{-5pt}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{minted}{\vspace{-5pt}}

\newminted{py}{frame=lines,
  framesep=2mm,
  baselinestretch=1.1,
  %bgcolor=mintbg,
  escapeinside=~~
 ,fontsize=\footnotesize
 ,fontfamily=courier
 ,breaklines=true
 ,xleftmargin=\shiftcodeleft
}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\begin{pycode}
  def __str__(self) -> str:
    return '|' + ''.join([f'{val}' for val in self.val]) + '>'

  def psi(self) -> State:
    return bitstring(*self.val)    
\end{pycode}
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{document}


Thanks for the reminder - I edited the question and added a reproduced.

Something like this?

You can adjust the spacing at the top and bottom to a desired value. Here is the MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

% Customizing the minted style to fix spacing
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\minted@framed@colorbg}%
  {\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}}% Adjust top spacing
  {\vspace{0.25\baselineskip}}% Replace with desired top spacing
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\endminted@framed}%
  {\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}}% Adjust bottom spacing
  {\vspace{0.25\baselineskip}}% Replace with desired bottom spacing
  {}{}
\makeatother

% Example code for testing
\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[frame=lines]{python}
# Example Python code
def hello_world():
    print("Hello, world!")
\end{minted}

\end{document}



Woussa - this is sheer magic! Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work with \newminted environments. Not quite sure what to do about that.
